# GitHub Actions fails while the script is working locally without no problem on self-hosted because NPM warnings

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub Actions fails while the bash script is working locally without no problem on self-hosted because NPM warnings.

Every time, on NPM warnings the script fails with the error: "Error: Process completed with exit code 1" only when running the script using Github Actions. The script works fine when i am running the script locally on the same SERVER i am running the actions-runner service.

When i am fixing the "NPM Warning" it goes fine but fail on the next warning.. i don't want to waste time on fixing that warnings but still want to use GitHub actions.

adding --silent to the npm install command solves the problem but I don't want to add it. why can't GitHub action just work according to the error level? why to fail according to the output text?

I also tried set CI variable to false but without success

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it's `debug` or any other issue with logging modules? Cause exit status `1` points on fatal error, so in case if you don't exit your program with `process.exit(1)` manually, probably something else does. Or some module really triggers it.

Comment: Did you check the return code when running it manually?